# docker CMD /sbin/init with insmod

Tags: docker

Could you let me know how to run `insmod` and `/sbin/init` in one CMD.

I wrote Dockerfile with one of bellow CMDs

```
CMD [ "insmod", "a_module.ko", "&&", "/sbin/init" ]
CMD insmod a_module.ko && /sbin/init
```

Then I run

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -p 4433:443 -it --rm -d --cap-add=ALL --privileged <image id>
```

It emit container ID, but the `docker ps` didn't show anything.
only second CMD could install `a_module`, but the process was not running.

Do you have any idea to run these two from one CMD?

**EDIT**

I would like to setup experimental environment in this container.

The `/sbin/init` is needed to run `systemctl` in docker.

`insmod` is not permitted from `RUN` even though it is from root. Currently it is done in container manually, but I would like to automate it

That's why insmod and /sbin/init are needed from `CMD`.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what do you want to achieve, explain why you need `CMD` and not `RUN`, show your Dockerfile

Comment: I guess that insmod is not restricted to the container but it will change the host kernel - docker is not a virtual machine thing.

To get away with systemctl/init one could also use the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script.

Answer (score 0):

To run more than one command with `CMD`, you would use:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "command1 && command2"]
```

Why you would want to try and run the full operating system services in the container by running `/sbin/init` is another question. It is not normal practice to do so. Containers would normally run one application only. Depending on how the container is setup when run, you may not even be able to run all normal operating system services or commands.